# How can I recover my Ubuntu 20.04 system after ubuntu-drivers-comon dist-upgrade?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, upgrade

My first question here. So, the problem is that I cannot boot ubuntu. Whenever I do, it shows the message:

> /dev/sdb4: clean, 228606/3219456 files, 3863110/12877056 blocks

and a blinking _ in the line below. This happened after I did the dist-upgrade on the package ubuntu-drivers-common. I had no problem until I shutdown my pc and turn it back on again. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot with windows. The sdb4 partition is the one where I have ubuntu installed. I was able to boot in recovery mode with Linux 5.4.0-29. Right now, I can only boot in recovery mode. Each time I boot without recovery mode, it shows the same message (only with slightly different values on the left sides of both slashes). I don't know if it's relevant, but I have a Nvidia graphics card.

How can I boot ubuntu normally again without having to do it on recovery mode? From my research there really isn't a clear way to rollback to the state before the dist-upgrade.

Comment: When it sticks on a block and the block changes it can be hardware failure.  You have a few options.  Try to boot gparted live disk and repair the partition disk. OR keep trying in recovery. If you can get to the Recovery then Enable networking and then command prompt.  From there sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.  If that does nothing then start over and sudo dpkg --configure -a.  Then look for forums and purge all nvidia drivers. And you are right.  Unless you have a clone backup you can't easily get back. For the future it is recommended to wait till 20.04.1 to do the upgrade.

Comment: @walttheboss thank you for your answer. I'm a bit skeptical on purging the nvidia drivers, since they usually are what makes my system work (nouveau drivers don't seem to work with my system). Do you think this can still be corrected with a future update or should I prepare to reinstall ubuntu from scratch? :/

Comment: If you have nothing to lose a fresh install can be the best.  There are huge changes from Ubuntu 18.04 and so a fresh install is highly recommended. Even purging can leave remnants sometimes.  I think that if it doesn't boot now then purging N-Vidia might do the same or better. Can't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this command solved the issue:

> sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Followed by reboot. No purge was necessary. Though it did cost almost 1 Gb of disk space.

Thank you to all that helped :)

Comment: Great followup. That helps people in the future. I recommend qdirstat to find out what is large on your drive. I imagine that the install put in lots of stuff you don't need.